# Class Component --> Expecting string/class/function got object --> component pass to other component -->react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

```js
// -----App.js

import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import News from './components/News';
import NewsItem from './components/NewsItem';


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <News />

    </div>

  );
}

export default App;


// ----- News.js

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import NewsItem from './NewsItem';

export class News extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NewsItem />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default News


//-----  NewsItem.js

import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class NewsItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          NewItem component
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default NewsItem
```

I am new to react and trying to learn the basics.I tried to resolve the issue but couldn't find out the actual cause. I tried to search same issue over the internet but can't find any. All though the error msg is same but situation is different.

> As you can see the NewsItem.js component is passed to News.js. Is it ok to pass a class component to another class component as a return type?

I'm getting the error as shown in img.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaiN0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove export before defining the class

```js
class News extends Component ...

class NewsItem extends Component ...
```

You are already default exporting it at the bottom